# Eth0 not working on Fresh install of 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, wired

i've just reinstalled my ubuntu 12.04 server with a clean install and i cannot get the networking to work, so i am unable to update the machine.

can anbody give me some advice on what solution i can try.

here is some info for you to work with.

```
$ip link

1: lo: <LOOPBACK, Up,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 cdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:0b:6a:dd:a6:f8 brd:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.223
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.226
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.228 192.168.5.253

$status networking
networking stop/waiting

$sudo service networking start
networking stop/waiting 

$sudo ifdown eth0
$sudo ifup -v eth0
configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: execute /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: execute /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 192.168.0.223/255.255.25.0 broadcast +           dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0    up
 ip route add default via 192.168.0.226 metric 100 dev eth0
run-parts --verbrose /etc/netwrok/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/netwrok/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/netwrok/if-up.d/ntdate
run-parts: executing /etc/netwrok/if-up.d/openssh-server
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 2111
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

the ip details are all correct. i know the network is up and running as i have used a windows computer to ping the ip address with no luck and i have tested the cables using a MAC Pro and they are active.

also just noticed when i plug the ethernet cable in the light doesnt appear on the switch

if you do need anymore info let me know

thanks

EDIT:

added ifup -v eth0 details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try replacing `iface eth0 inet dhcp` instead of `static adress` etc...

Worked for me, but I don't really know more about eth0 config.

Comment: no that didnt work, it still says networking stop/waiting and also under ifconfig the inet line disappears

Comment: Are there any clues here? sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0 Thanks.

Comment: `sudo ifdown eth0` seems to work.
`sudo ifup eth0` comes back with ssh stop/waiting, ssh start/running, process 1776. but this doesnt get the connectivity running

Comment: Usually the -v flag will provide some clues as to what's going wrong. Did you do ifup eth0 or ifup _-v_ eth0?

Comment: sorry i did miss the -v flag, however i have no idea what to make of what comes up. i will add what i see to the my main post